# Weird symbols from NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsxmlparser

I'm stuck with a problem; everything I try to parse with the `NSXMLParser` ends up with "†Êá"(name of element, elementText ...)

I tried different sources (the one I'd like to parse from my server, simple `NSString`, and from different sources from the web which deliver XML) and every time "†Êá".

```
//prepar request
//NSString *urlString = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102:8080/support/supportService"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
//if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
 NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
 // responsecode here
 //}

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: [ result dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
//NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: [ fakeResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[parser setDelegate:self]; // The parser calls methods in this class
//[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; // We don't care about namespaces
//[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; //
//[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; // We just want data, no other stuff

[parser parse]; // Parse that data..
```

and the delegate methods

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
      NSLog(@"chars: %s", string);
  }

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


  NSLog(@"open: %s %s, %s", elementName, namespaceURI, qName);
   }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {


   NSLog(@"close: %s", elementName); 
   }
```

i also tried different encodings such as ANSI and UTF8 .. but still I get the following results:

```
2010-02-17 09:29:18.377 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] Response Code: 200
2010-02-17 09:29:18.378 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] Response: <?xml version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8"?><Books><Book id="1"><title>Circumference</title><author>Nicholas  
Nicastro</author><summary>Eratosthenes and the Ancient Quest to Measure the   
Globe.</summary></Book><Book id="2"><title>Copernicus Secret</title><author>Jack  
Repcheck</author><summary>How the scientific revolution began</summary></Book><Book 
id="3"><title>Angels and Demons</title><author>Dan Brown</author><summary>Robert 
Langdon is summoned to a Swiss research facility to analyze a cryptic symbol seared into 
the chest of a murdered physicist.</summary></Book><Book id="4"><title>Keep the 
Aspidistra Flying</title><author>George Orwell</author><summary>A poignant and 
ultimately hopeful look at class and society, Keep the Aspidistra Flying pays tribute 
to the stubborn virtues of ordinary people who keep the aspidistra 
flying.</summary></Book></Books>
2010-02-17 09:29:18.379 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.381 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.381 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.382 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] chars: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.382 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] close: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.383 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.383 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] chars: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.384 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] close: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.384 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.385 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] chars: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.385 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] close: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.386 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] close: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.386 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.387 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.387 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] chars: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.388 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] close: †Êá
2010-02-17 09:29:18.388 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] open: †Êá (null), (null)
2010-02-17 09:29:18.389 SupportServiceWSTest[403:20b] chars: †Êá
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is the fact that you're using `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. The XML is UTF8 encoded (as specified in the XML response), so you should be using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Another the problem is that you're using %s in your `NSLog` calls for `NSString` Objects, which won't work. %s is for C strings, null terminated character arrays, not objects. Replace %s with %@.

%@ when used in `NSLog` will call the `description` method on any object that is its matching argument. For `NSString`s description will print out the contents of the string.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! as i said it has nothing to do with the encoding (despite im using a wrong ne here in my excample i changed it to any combination)

but the %s -> %@ trick dit it! im using objc for only a week now and im not that familiar with it. i think you saved me weeks on this problem really!! :D